# angular 5. translation- manipulate all keys before translation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngx-translate

In my app I am using ngx-translate.
I need to do some manipulation on all the keys based on user information.

For example-

The code in the template is *a.b.c*, if the user choose in some input field *x* we will first try to look for *a.b.c.x* key and if it doesn't exist- search for the original code.
I need to it for all the keys in the system (in the real logic I need to add more info in the key)

Is there any way to perform this logic to all of my keys before translation in only one place instead of in each component?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom pipe that extends the `ngx-translate` translate pipe.
Something like this :

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'customTranslate',
  pure: false
})
export class CustomTranslatePipe extends TranslatePipe {
transform(query: string, ...args: any[]): any {
  const modifiedQuery = query + '.x';
  const result = super.transform(modifiedQuery, args);
  return result !== modifiedQuery ? result : super.transform(query, args);
}
```

And use it instead of the translate pipe :

```
{{ 'a.b.c' | customTranslate }}
```

Comment: Thanks!! I want to do something like-  
            const a = super.transform(query + '.x', args);
            if (!a){
                return super.transform(query, args);
            }
            return a;
but now I have another problem- my MissingTranslationHandler returns the string after the last dot if the code isn't found. after debugging I can see that the transform happens after the  MissingTranslationHandler operation, so I can not recognize that the code is not exist. Do you have any idea how can I solve it besides rewriting MissingTranslationHandler to return null?

Comment: thanks, but my MissingTranslationHandler returns the last string after the last dot, for example if the code is a.b.c.x but it is missing, x will be returned (but the is a chance that x is the actual translation for all the code, so I can't recognize this situation). Maybe I will return all code from MissingTranslationHandler and not just the last string after the dot.

Comment: And a last question- my pipe needs to include two params that will be in the suffix of the code. these params are saved in a service. what is the preferred way to use them in the pipe- pass them as an argument like  {{'a.b.c' | customTranslate: 'x'}} in each template or inject the service in the constructor of the pipe like-     constructor(translate: TranslateService, _ref: ChangeDetectorRef, service: MyService) {
        super(translate, _ref); 
    }

Comment: You could use the `TranslateService.instant` to check if the key exists, which doesn't call the MissingTranslationHandler unlike the get method.

Comment: I try to use TranslateService.instant but it is still calling MissingTranslationHandler  first..

Comment: I made a stackblitz, it works but it has a weird behavior with value changing at startup : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-53029885

Comment: because of this apparently- "This method is synchronous and the default file loader is asynchronous. You are responsible for knowing when your translations have been loaded and it is safe to use this method. If you are not sure then you should use the get method instead." according the example MissingTranslationHandler  should not be invoked because we do have a translation to "HOME"